# ¿Cómo se dice "mondegreen" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

[Mondegreen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mondegreen) se define como

> : a word or phrase that results from a mishearing of something said or sung.

Es decir, el malentendido resultante de haber oido mal lo dicho (o cantado) por otra persona. Un ejemplo en español sería entender "¡Que viene Genaro!" cuando lo que se ha dicho en realidad es "¡Qué bien he cenado!".

En Wikipedia proponen [**pomporruta**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomporruta), pero dado su origen (confusión en la letra de un himno de Falange Española) dudo que sea conocida fuera de España y, en cualquier caso, no aparece en el DLE.

Comment: Buena pregunta. Desde hace un tiempo en España se ha popularizado la expresión "momento [teniente](https://dle.rae.es/teniente)" para cuando una canción en otro idioma parecía que decía algo en español, un ejemplo es la canción "All Right" de Christopher Cross, que en el estribillo dice "I think we're gonna make it" but the people kept hearing "pingüino Rodríguez". Esta expresión parece que se usa solo en canciones en idiomas extranjeros, así que es más restrictiva que "pomporruta", la cual por cierto no había oído nunca.

Comment: Cuando se dice tal malentendido (y no solo se escucha) se llama un malapropismo. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropismo

Comment: Guantanamera changed to: Aguanta la mera. ..... John Prine Misheard Lyrics:
It's a happy enchilada and you think you're gonna drown
The Real Lyrics:
It's a half an inch of water and you think you're gonna drown

Answer (score 3):

Hay un fenómeno bastante habitual, de reinterpretar con el propio léxico el sonido de frases de un léxico que no comprendemos (sobretodo si es otro idioma). Esto ocurre a menudo en los niños (léxico reducido).

Muchos himnos antiguos y canciones extranjeras son material para re-escribir el sonido de sus palabras usando palabras distintas que suenan similar, con la intención de sátira o parodia.

En España le llaman "pomporruta"; en Inglaterra, "mondegreen"; en Japón, "soramimi" (oreja de aire).

En lingüistica, se denomina PARAFASIA (si es involuntario) o TRANSLITERACIÓN HOMOFÓNICA (si es voluntario).

Personalmente, me he fijado que el concepto japonés SORAMIMI es conocido tanto en el idioma inglés como en el idioma español, debido a la difusión mundial que ha tenido un juego televisivo llamado así. No sería raro que este concepto siga el mismo destino de la universalmente conocida palabra KARAOKE.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco una palabra precisa, pero existe una expresión que la describe gráficamente, producida por efecto de un

> teléfono descompuesto

Supongo que este juego infantil resulta suficientemente conocido en muchos países de habla hispana. Básicamente consiste en una manera de hacer circular un mensaje de forma individual, dentro de una rueda de personas. Cada participante a un turno transmite al próximo —secretamente al oído, y tan literalmente como pueda— lo que oyó de su vecino. Normalmente se trata de una frase o historia corta. La gracia del juego está en finalmente comprobar el grado de deformación que ese mensaje sufre, por efecto de las sucesivas transferencias.

No sólo es divertido, sino también un buen ejemplificador de las dificultades que entraña la comunicación, y la deriva semántica que puede adquirir lo dicho por alguien con la suma de distorsiones introducidas por los distintos receptores y emisores.

Aludir a un efecto de "teléfono descompuesto" es una manera directa de representar los malentendidos que ocurren en la comunicación humana, y perfectamente ilustra el sentido de "***mondegreen***"

> (...)
> Cuando por fin alcancé la puerta del elevador, escuché el rumor que comenzaba en la boca de Francesca y se extendía de boca en oreja cual teléfono descompuesto: –¡Es un artista! –¡Es una pista! –¡Es un taxista! –¡Es un nazista! Subí en el ...

(extracto de uso del libro "Te vendo un perro" de Claudio Villalobos, para ejemplificar la aceptación general de la expresión conocida (de [esta búsqueda en google.books](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=HGnkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&dq=%22telefono+descompuesto%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOto75l6zrAhWkD7kGHXrYDqI4ChDoATACegQIBhAC))

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser una **tergiversación** o una **distorsión**

Para tergiversar el DRAE dice:

> 1. tr. Dar una interpretación forzada o errónea a palabras o acontecimientos.
> 2. tr. Trastrocar, trabucar

(https://dle.rae.es/tergiversar)

Para distorsión, en su segunda acepción dice

> 2. Deformación de imágenes, sonidos, señales, etc., producida en su transmisión o reproducción.

(https://dle.rae.es/distorsi%C3%B3n)