# ¿Tiene nombre el uso deliberado de una palabra con un significado diferente del que tiene?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, lingüística, recurso-retórico

¿Tiene nombre el recurso ¿estilístico? ¿retórico? de utilizar deliberadamente una palabra con un significado completamente diferente de el que esa palabra realmente tiene?

Algo en la línea de lo indicado por Lewis Carroll en "A través del espejo y lo que Alicia encontró allí" (cap. 6) cuando pone en boca de Humpty Dumpty:

"Cuando yo uso una palabra -insistió Humpty Dumpty con
un tono de voz más bien desdeñoso- quiere decir lo que yo
quiero que diga…, ni más ni menos."

Por delimitar claramente la cuestión, tomemos como ejemplo la frase "**El sábado vamos a organizar en casa una umbelífera por todo lo alto para celebrar tu cumpleaños**" y supongamos, además, que es un uso deliberado y consciente, que la persona que la pronuncia conoce perfectamente el significado real de *umbelífera* y que no está utilizando una clave o una jerga privada del grupo al que se dirige.

Una [**umbelífera**](https://dle.rae.es/umbel%C3%ADfero) es, por supuesto,

> 1. adj. Bot. Dicho de una planta: Del grupo de las angiospermas dicotiledóneas, con hojas por lo común alternas, simples, más o menos divididas y con pecíolos envainadores, flores blancas o amarillas en umbela, y fruto compuesto por dos aquenios, en cada uno de los cuales hay una sola semilla de albumen carnoso o córneo; p. ej., el cardo corredor, el apio, el perejil, el hinojo, el comino o la zanahoria.

Está claro por el contexto que, en este caso, la palabra *umbelífera* no se emplea en su sentido habitual, sino que sustituye a la palabra *fiesta* u otra similar.

Este uso no es un [**gazapo**](https://dle.rae.es/gazapo) (negrita mia)

> 2. m. coloq. Yerro que **por inadvertencia** deja escapar quien escribe o habla.

porque es deliberado y conociendo el significado real de las palabras.

Tampoco es un [**tropo**](https://dle.rae.es/tropo) (negrita mia)

> 2. m. Ret. Empleo de una palabra en sentido distinto del que propiamente le corresponde, pero que **tiene con este alguna conexión, correspondencia o semejanza**.

porque falta esa "conexión. correspondencia o semejanza" de la definición de tropo.

Tampoco es, y por un motivo análogo, una [**metáfora**](https://dle.rae.es/met%C3%A1fora) (negrita mía)

> 1. f. Ret. Traslación del sentido recto de una voz a otro figurado, en virtud de una **comparación tácita**, como en *las perlas del rocío, la primavera de la vida o refrenar las pasiones.*

un [**simil**](https://dle.rae.es/s%C3%ADmil)

> 3. m. Ret. Producción de una idea viva y eficaz de una cosa relacionándola con otra también expresa, como en *el oro de tus cabellos* por *tus cabellos rubios*.

una [**metonimia**](https://dle.rae.es/metonimia)

> 1. f. Ret. Tropo que consiste en designar algo con el nombre de otra cosa tomando el efecto por la causa o viceversa, el autor por sus obras, el signo por la cosa significada, etc.; p. ej., *las canas* por *la vejez*; *leer a Virgilio*, por *leer las obras de Virgilio*; *el laurel* por *la gloria*, etc

o una [**sinécdoque**](https://dle.rae.es/sin%C3%A9cdoque)

> 1. f. *Ret*. Designación de una cosa con el nombre de otra, de manera similar a la metonimia, aplicando a un todo el nombre de una de sus partes, o viceversa, a un género el de una especie, o al contrario, a una cosa el de la materia de que está formada, etc., como en *cien cabezas* por *cien reses*, en *los mortales* por *los seres humanos*, en *el acero* por *la espada*, etc.

Claramente tampoco es un [**eufemismo**](https://dle.rae.es/eufemismo)

> 1. m. Manifestación suave o decorosa de ideas cuya recta y franca expresión sería dura o malsonante.

porque no hay nada "duro  o malsonante" en la palabra sustituida.

Como no hay parecido sonoro o escrito entre las palabras, tampoco es un caso de [***mondegreen***](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/c%C3%B3mo-se-dice-mondegreen-en-espa%C3%B1ol) , [**pomporruta**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomporruta), [**tergiversación**](https://dle.rae.es/tergiversar), etc.

¿Cómo se denomina, pues, este uso?

EDICION
Quisiera aclarar que por lo que pregunto **no** es el recurso de adscribir **de un modo permanente** un significado a la palabra en cuestión, **ni** utilizarla como **palabra comodin** o **muletilla**.
Por volver al ejemplo, el mismo hablante en otra ocasión podría utilizar la misma palabra "umbelífera" con un significado diferente a "fiesta" pero que igualmente se pudiera conocer por el contexto [por ejemplo: "Lo que más me gusta del parque de atracciones es montarme en los coches de choque y chocar con umbeliferas que apenas tienen edad para manejarlos" - aquí, "umbelífera" = "jóvenes, adolescentes"] o utilizar otra palabra diferente con el mismo sentido de "fiesta" (por ejemplo, "escarpia": "**El sábado vamos a organizar en casa una escarpia por todo lo alto para celebrar tu cumpleaños**").

Comment: Tergiversar es dar una interpretación forzada o errónea a palabras o acontecimientos, lo cual funciona perfectamente sobre el papel, pero suena raro en el contexto de un uso jocoso o festivo de una palabra.

Comment: Mientras que algún experto en el tema provee más información, yo diría que busques información relacionada a: significado de connotación (aquí un poco https://www.significados.com/connotacion/). Y el asunto se complica porque hay muchos regionalismos. Respecto a metonimia, eufemismo, etc., son todas *figuras literarias*, hay más de ellas que quizá quieras investigar..

Comment: sinónimos idiolectales, diria yo.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no es oficialmente un *recurso*, pero podríamos llamarlo... ¿un **juego**?

Wikipedia tiene una lista de [figuras retóricas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Figuras_ret%C3%B3ricas).

Uno que aplica pero no perfecto es [nonsense](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsense):

> Nonsense es un género jocoso y figura literaria que puede ser expresado en verso o en prosa e incluso de un modo «libre» normal, buscando generar juegos de palabras que trasgreden las formas comunes de la sintaxis y la semántica, juegos que resultan extraños, comúnmente humorísticos y absurdos.

Otro que se acerca es [catacresis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catacresis) :

> La catacresis o abusión es una figura retórica que consiste en utilizar metafóricamente una palabra para designar una realidad que carece de un término específico. [...] Catacresis también puede referirse al vicio sintáctico del lenguaje en el cual se emplea una palabra por otra, que también existe pero con diferentes significados. Su existencia puede implicar problemas de acentuación diacrítica.

Comment: *Catacresis* me parece una propuesta bastante interesante. Creo que es la palabra que buscamos.

Answer (score 0):

Un término que se pudiera emplear es [neologismo](https://dle.rae.es/neologismo).  Se utiliza en psiquiatría en relación al [lenguaje de los esquizofrénicos](https://www.elsigma.com/colaboraciones/la-funcion-del-neologismo-en-la-esquizofrenia-y-la-etica-de-la-intervencion-del-analista/1191).  Aunque en este contexto se refiere al empleo de palabras nuevas, no existentes. Según la definición de la RAE se puede utilizar también para referirse a nuevas acepciones de una palabra.